# Disable SSH Timeouts

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ubuntu-11.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ssh terminal session times out, how can this be changed](https://superuser.com/questions/347562/ssh-terminal-session-times-out-how-can-this-be-changed)

When ever I connect to a server using SSH with multiple windows, few connections get closed. It is probably because of ideal time. I have followed through this blog https://www.simplified.guide/ssh/disable-timeout and its not working for me. I don't have permission the server to make changes. I there any way to disable or extend the connection time. I am using Ubuntu 11.04

Thank you

Answer (score 8):

You can add the following to your local `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` file (`man ssh_config`):

```
ServerAliveInterval 60
```

where `60` is in seconds. This will cause your client to send a message to the SSH server every `60` seconds which should keep the connection alive.

You can also use `screen` to open multiple terminals on one connection (`apt-get install screen`). A nice thing about screen is that you can disconnect from the server but your processes keep running and you can reconnect later using `screen -R`. I think this is the best way, personally.

If you had access to the server configs, you could also update the `ClientAliveInterval` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on the server (`man sshd_config`).