# ssh terminal session times out, how can this be changed

Tags: linux, ssh, bsd

It seems after about 5 minutes an inactive ssh session is terminated. The server is Ubuntu. How can I change this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On the server, login as root and edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and add the line:

```
ClientAliveInterval 60
```

man sshd_config:

> Sets a timeout interval in seconds after which if no data has been
>   received from the client, sshd(8) will send a message through the
>   encrypted channel to request a response from the client. The default
>   is 0, indicating that these messages will not be sent to the client.
>   This option applies to protocol version 2 only.

You'll need to restart the `sshd` for it to come into effect.

Alternatively on the client edit `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` (if you have root and want it for all users) or `~/.ssh/config` and add the line:

```
ServerAliveInterval 60
```