# Timeout access with Shell

Tags: security, debian, putty, root

Hi I have a Debian 6  Webserver to which I can connect with Putty.
But if I leave Putty open then even after 2 days I am still logged in.

I have got 2 questions:

1. How can I make sure that I will be logged out after an Idle time of lets say one hour.
2. How can I disable Root Acces.

Many thanks

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/347562/ssh-terminal-session-times-out-how-can-this-be-changed

Comment: Please confine each question to a single question, and please search first.

Answer (score 1):

Edit your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

for 1. check these options, I think that should do the trick:

```
ClientAliveInterval 30
ClientAliveCountMax 120
```

Explanation from `man 5 sshd_config`:

> ```
> ClientAliveCountMax
> ```
>
> Sets the number of client alive messages (see below) which may be sent without sshd(8) receiving any messages back from
>                the client.  If this threshold is reached while client alive messages are being sent, sshd will disconnect the client,
>                terminating the session.  It is important to note that the use of client alive messages is very different from
>                TCPKeepAlive (below).  The client alive messages are sent through the encrypted channel and therefore will not be spoofa‐
>                ble.  The TCP keepalive option enabled by TCPKeepAlive is spoofable.  The client alive mechanism is valuable when the
>                client or server depend on knowing when a connection has become inactive.
>
> The default value is 3.  If ClientAliveInterval (see below) is set to 15, and ClientAliveCountMax is left at the default,
>                unresponsive SSH clients will be disconnected after approximately 45 seconds.  This option applies to protocol version 2
>                only.
>
> ```
> ClientAliveInterval
> ```
>
> Sets a timeout interval in seconds after which if no data has been received from the client, sshd(8) will send a message
>                through the encrypted channel to request a response from the client.  The default is 0, indicating that these messages
>                will not be sent to the client.  This option applies to protocol version 2 only.

for 2. set `PermitRootLogin no`; there are also other possible values:

> ```
>  PermitRootLogin
> ```
>
> Specifies whether root can log in using ssh(1).  The argument must be “yes”, “without-password”, “forced-commands-only”,
>                or “no”.  The default is “yes”.
>
> If this option is set to “without-password”, password authentication is disabled for root.
>
> If this option is set to “forced-commands-only”, root login with public key authentication will be allowed, but only if
>                the command option has been specified (which may be useful for taking remote backups even if root login is normally not
>                allowed).  All other authentication methods are disabled for root.
>
> If this option is set to “no”, root is not allowed to log in.

Right (from old answer as noticed in comments): You need to restart SSH daemon: `/etc/init.d/sshd restart`.