# Why are my Linux Server users conection closed by my linux server

Tags: linux, putty

On a linux box I created 10 user accounts. They were able to putty and ftp to the linuxServer. I installed minecraft server. Now the users of the 10 accounts can login but the connection automatically gets closed by Linux server. I can still login with putty. My users get an error connection closed by remote host. How can I fix this so my 10 users can login again?

Comment: "connection automatically gets closed by remote host" you mean "connection automatically gets closed by my Linux box"... Which connections are closed, putty or minecraft?

Comment: What does /var/log/secure say?

Comment: Yes my users get the message "connection closed by remote server".  there is no /var/log/secure.  There is /var/log/syslog and /var/log/messages as well as other files in log.  I do not know what to look for.

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: Maybe you're running out of RAM

Comment: You may want to look at my answer to a similar question, but set the timeout to higher values: http://superuser.com/a/569357/195224

Answer (score 0):

Are the connections idle? If so, add this to /etc/ssh/sshd_config on the server:

```
TCPKeepAlive yes
ClientAliveInterval 60
```

and reload the sshd:

```
$ sudo service ssh reload
```

Answer (score 0):

The environmental setting `TMOUT` is used to automatically log inactive users out. The default is 300 seconds (5 minutes).

Either adjust the `TMOUT` setting, or to stop auto-logouts completely set to zero, in users `.bash_profile` (or set system-wide in `/etc/profile`)

```
export TMOUT=0
```